# Is ionCube PHP Encoder PHP accelelator?

Tags: php, ioncube

So I´m testing out some PHP accelelators and came across ionCube PHP Encoder.

I´ve installed it and phpinfo says that it is loaded:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

So I thought to check how it runs, but unfortunately I cannot find any statistics,change any configuration for encoder or even see if it is working (HTTP response does not have "X-Accelerated-By" value).

By doing some research, it seems to me that **ionCube Encoder** is separate application that encodes files before sending them to LIVE environment (for example) and **loader** displays encoded content.

Now the question is: Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Where did you read that ionCube "accelerates" your code?

Comment: [Our Encoder also optimises code to reduce size and gain some performance (our paper on PHP Accelerator Internals gives an example of the optimiser in action).](http://www.ioncube.com/about.php) Therefore I thought that they implemented PHP accelelator into Encoder and thus having encoding and accelelator capabilities. Once again, I might have misunderstood it. And also this [site](http://www.extensionsmall.com/blog/ioncube-facts-and-performance-concerns) advertises that ionCube has optimizer, which boosts script performance.